# Initializing and Declaring objects and methods

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have the following the problem, and I'm not sure how to solve it. I'm looking for suggestions. I have an instance data (see below). This is what I'm trying to do:

The killring should be initialized to `new KillList()` when declared or in the constructor.

`private KillList killring;`

KillList is a child class to another class. The overall program deals with Lists: LinkedLists and ArrayList. **The constructor add elements from the ArrayList into Killring. A new node is added each time to the end of the linkelist.**

This is what I have so far:

```
public class AssassinManager {

private static class AssassinNode {
    private String player; 
    private String killer; 
    private AssassinNode next;
    private AssassinNode(String name) { // to be altered 
        this.player = name; 
        this.killer = null; 
        this.next = null;
    } 
}// End of AssassinNode - DONE

private KillList killring; //KillList object
private AssassinNode graveyard; //AssassinNodeData object 

/* Constructor add names from arralyist to killring 
without altering elements in arraylist */
public AssassinManager (ArrayList<String> players) {
    if (players == null || players.isEmpty() == true) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    killring = new AssassinNode(players.get(0)); // AN ERROR IS PRESENTED HERE
}
```

This is what I have so far for KillList :

```
public class KillList extends AssassinNodeData {

public KillList(String player) {
    super(player);
}
```

Possible answer:

```
public AssassinManager (ArrayList<String> players) {
    if (players == null || players.isEmpty() == true) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    killring = new KillList(players.get(0));
    KillList node = killring; 
    for (int i = 1; i < players.size(); i++) {
        node.next = new KillList(players.get(i));
        node = node.next; 
    }
}
```

Comment: **What** error? Oh, a `KillList` is not an `AssassinNode`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  incompatible can't cast AssassinNode to KillList class

Comment: Presumably `AssassinNode` should extend (or implement) `KillList`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Couldn't tell you without seeing `KillList`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  I updated and added KillList()

Comment: What kind of relationship do you actually expect to have between an `AssasinNode` and a `KillList`. An analogy of what you are doing right now would be: a customer requests a car, but you create and send him a bicycle. The extend thing Elliott talks about is like saying a client wants a vehicle and you send him a car. Or do you want an `AssassinNode` to contain a `KillList`?

Comment: @OliPro007 The whole program is like a game. Each node represents a person and then they get "killed" by the previous person in the node. Maybe I'm not building the constructor right - in that I may not need the AssassinNode passing in after all. I just updated the question. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: The big problem I can see is that `KillList` extends `AssasinNodeData`, not `AssassinNode`, that is why it doesn't work. I don't know the exact purpose of `KillList`, but if it is some kind of graveyard and the `AssasinNode` is a player, then the `KillList` would contain all the dead players, not be a player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it won't compile is that you are calling the constructor of `AssasinNode` to create a `KillList`, you need to use the constructor of `KillList` instead, so `killring = new KillList(players.get(0))`.

However I would like to point out a little logic mistake: you are creating a "KillList", yet it cannot contain more that one player. If you want a proper list, you need to add a list member field and the proper methods to add and remove from that list inside `KillList`.

Comment: You're right! I just updated to the result. As for KillList() - it is still work in progress. There are three classes: KillList(), AssassinNodeData(), and AssassinNodeClient(), and AssassinNodeManager().

Comment: @Ani Alright then! If you think this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer. If you need more help, don't hesitate to update your question or post another one with your progress.